# Android make layout and use it again

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

I have my main activity. Inside this main activity I want to create an unknown number of layouts that each one of them include one button.
I want smart way to do it - make the layout one time and than use it a lot of time.

[image]

What is a good way to do it?
Thanks

Comment: I think it is. but what do I do about the unknown number of layouts i need. Is there a way to do it programlly?

Comment: When asking questions on StackOverflow please do some research before asking: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%5D+add+a+layout+programmatically Also what you ask is covered by the various free online Android courses. This site works best with specific programming question where you show what you've tried.

Comment: You can **not** create a view **one** time and use it **multiple times**. Android does not like it, and will you an exception. I have tried.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make One Layout Resource File Using Below Code

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_100sdp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_15sdp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_13sdp" />
    
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_35sdp"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_20sdp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Submit"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_10sdp" />
    
    </LinearLayout>
```

And In Your Main Activity Layout You Can Use Only

```
  <include layout="@layout/layoutresourcefilename"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Trying to be smart commonly results in the opposite. Better keep it simple;
Which means, just add three buttons and then show either one of them.
This has the advance, that the events are already bound, ready to click.

And also, meanwhile it's a whole lot more common to inflate `Fragment`
or to data-bind views, which would permit for hiding/showing buttons.